# Intelligent modal with Facebook Like box

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I have one thing to make intelligent modal window with facebook like box. Intelligence is in not disturbing first time visitor and all visitors that has liked my FB page. Step by step logic is:

1. Check cookie, if visitor is here for first time, create cookie with visit time and do nothing.
2. If visitor returned to site after minimum 24 hours, check if logged in user has liked my FB page. If yes, do nothing.
3. If returned visitor does not liked my FB page in past, dim browser and display modal (popup) window with facebook like box.
4. If visitor close modal window without liking FB page, set cookie to do not disturb him anymore.

Sorry for my english. I'm dummy programmer, If you can help me to do this in PHP (for Wordpress as plugin), or if you thing that same plugin exist, please send me a link and I will buy this plugin.

Thank you.

Comment: Like gating is not allowed.

Comment: OK, remove thist feature, display modal for all, but only once and only on second visit.

Comment: Use a cookie and bump it for every visit